# Как в double записать число 0.50, а не 0.5?

Tags: c#, double

Как в double записать число 0.50, а не 0.5?

Comment: Это одно и то же число. _Ваш К. О._

Comment: Сдаётся мне, вас интересует на самом деле форматирование вывода.

Comment: Да, мне необходимо, условно, записать 0.50 чтобы потом перевести число в строку "0.50" и сконкатенировать с "5" и снова перевести в double 0.505. А не 0.55

Comment: Сконкатенировать?? Ох. Вы идёте каким-то очень странным путём. Расскажите, для чего вам это.

Comment: Кастомный калькулятор, пользователь вводит 0.5 в форме, 0.5 сохраняется в double, после чего добавляет к 0.5 ещё и 0, double становится 0.50 и добавляет 5, в double записывается 0,505

Число к double добавляется через конкатенацию (value = Convert.ToDouble(valueToString() + tag);

если "0" не добавить, 0.505 не получится

Comment: @ВиталийИвановский так вам надо смотреть в сторону TryParse(). Держите отображение числа в строке, к строке прибавляйте ноль, потом парсите строку и сохраняйте её в double временную переменную, когда над ней нужно будет совершать какие либо действия

Comment: Окей, понял. Вы делаете не совсем верно. Держите пользовательский ввод в виде и строки, и числа. Потому что операции типа «убрать последнюю цифру» очень сложно правильно сделать на числе типа double.

Comment: Идея хорошая, изначально и планировалось завести число и строку, но думал обойдусь числом

Comment: @ВиталийИвановский я обновил комментарий свой. Прочтите. Вам не нужно хранить и в строке, и в числе сразу всё. Достаточно хранить только строку в textBox'е, а потом парсить её и преобразовывать в число, когда нужно будет совершать операции

Comment: @KitScribe, увидел, спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Парсить строку придётся после каждого ввода, чтобы юзер не ввёл какую-нибудь чепуху

Comment: @ВиталийИвановский можно же ограничения поставить на то, чтобы только numeric данные вводились. Плюс TryParse() не будет возбуждать исключение, если были введены буквы, а вот Parse уже зарайзит exception

Comment: @VladD реализовал калькулятор с использованием строк и чисел, вышло лаконичнее и операции типа «убрать последнюю цифру» решаются довольно просто. Спасибо!

Comment: @ВиталийИвановский: Пожалуйста! Рад, что советы помогли!

Comment: чтобы вопрос не висел, дополните его своими уточнениями из комментариев. В текущем виде он не слишком полезен, но его вполне можно привести к нормальному виду. Также вы можете написать к нему ответ самостоятельно, либо попросить сделать это тех, кто вам помог комментариями.